# Let V,W be vector spaces over Q, and let T:V→W be a function. Prove that if T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2) for all v1,v2∈V, then T is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V,W be vector spaces over Q, and let T:V→W be a function. Prove that if

T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2)

for all v1,v2 ∈ V, then T is linear.

All I study is that T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2) is a property of linear maps. But this question reverses it, giving the equation first, and then tell us to prove it linear. So far, I have no idea towards this question. Anybody can give a hint or advice?

Comment: also see (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377534/show-that-additive-functions-are-linear-if-the-vector-spaces-are-defined-over)

Comment: Since you already have the additive property, just verify that $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v), \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$. Look at this link, this exercise will help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377534/show-that-additive-functions-are-linear-if-the-vector-spaces-are-defined-over