# $\alpha (a + b) = \alpha (a) + \alpha (b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$ show that $\alpha$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, continuous-homomorphisms

The question is:

Let $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a cts. function which satisfies $\alpha (a + b) = \alpha (a) + \alpha (b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$ show that $\alpha$ is a linear transformation.

I had seen this other question here on this site:

[Show that additive functions are linear if the vector spaces are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377534/show-that-additive-functions-are-linear-if-the-vector-spaces-are-defined-over)

I want someone to explain to me how continuity here makes the function $\alpha$ a linear transformation? it seems like continuity substitutes for the field being $\mathbb{Q}$ in the mentioned link.

If anyone can show me why $\alpha $  is linear transformation and  compare between the 2 exercises, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "Cauchy functional equation".

Comment: The key is that if $r$ is a real number, then there exists a sequence of rationals $q_n$ such that $q_n\to r$, and hence $\alpha(r) = \lim \alpha(q_n)$. So if you know it for rationals, you can then deduce the necessary property for reals.

Comment: So what is the difference in the proof between the 2 exercises? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @hopefully: taking the limit in the end to conclude

Comment: @hopefully: One only requires $\alpha(qx) = q\alpha(x)$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, the other requires $\alpha(rx) = r\alpha(x)$ ro $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Do you see the difference now?

Comment: So you need to prove that if $\alpha(a) + \alpha(b)=\alpha (a+b)$ for all $a,b$ $\implies \alpha(r*a) = r\alpha(a)$ for all $r$?  Well, use induction to prove that must be true for $r \in \mathbb Q$ and if $r \not \in \mathbb Q$ then let $q_i \to r$ and as $\alpha$ is continuous $\alpha (ra) = \lim \alpha (q_ia) =\lim q_i\alpha (a) = r\alpha (a)$.

Comment: but here in our question, are the vector spaces (instead of V and W) $\mathbb{R}$ ? are we considering the field is $\mathbb{R}$ also?

Comment: In this question you are considering $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prove that $\alpha(ra) = r\alpha(a)$ for all $r,a\in \mathbb R$. (You are considering $\mathbb R$ as vector space over itself.)

$\alpha(0) = \alpha(0+0) = \alpha(0) + \alpha (0)$ so $\alpha (0)=0$.

And $\alpha(a) + \alpha(-a) = \alpha(a+(-a)) = \alpha(0) = 0$ so $\alpha(-a)=-\alpha(a)$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$.

So $\alpha(0*a) = \alpha (0) = 0 =0\alpha(a)$ so the proposition is true if $r=0$

And $\alpha(1*a) = \alpha(a) =1*\alpha (a)$ so the proposition is true if $r = 1$.

If the proposition is true for $r=n \in N$ then $\alpha ((n+1)a)=\alpha (na + a) = \alpha(na) +\alpha (a) = n\alpha(a) + \alpha(a)=(n+1)\alpha(a)$ so it is true for $r=n+1$.

So by induction it is true for all $r\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ and as $\alpha(-na)=-\alpha(na) = -n\alpha(a)$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ the proposition is true for $r\in \mathbb Z$.

And for $r = \frac mn \in \mathbb Q; m\in \mathbb  Z; n\in \mathbb N$ we have $\underbrace{\alpha(\frac mna) + ... + \alpha(\frac mna)}_{n\text{ times}}= \alpha (n*\frac mna) =\alpha(ma)=m\alpha(a)$ so $\alpha(\frac mn a) = \frac mn\alpha(a)$.  So the proposition is true if $r\in \mathbb Q$.

**Now here is where you need continuity**:

Let $r\in \mathbb R$ and let $q_i\in \mathbb Q$ so that $q_i\to r$.

Then $r\alpha(a) = (\lim_{i\to\infty} q_i)\alpha (a) = \lim_{i\to\infty} q_i\alpha (a))=\lim_{i\to\infty}\alpha(q_ia)$.  But $\alpha$ is continuous so $\lim_{i\to\infty}\alpha(q_ia)=\alpha(ra)$

So the proposition is true for all $r \in \mathbb R$.